# static const std::vector

Tags: c++, static, constants, private-members

I am writing an image viewer with Qt.
I am trying to do the following in the header file:

```
class ImageModel
{


private:
    const static std::vector<int> mZoomLevels;

}
```

in the source file:

```
int zooms[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
const std::vector<int> mZoomLevels(zooms.begin(),zooms.end());
```

However I get the following error:

> request for member 'begin' in zooms which is of non-class type 'int[10]'
>   request for member 'end' in zooms which is of non-class type 'int[10]'

Does anyone know how to initialize this static const private member ?

Comment: Should that be `const std::vector<int> ImageModel::mZoomLevels(...)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plain arrays do not have member functions. I believe you're looking for this:

```
int zooms[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
const std::vector ImageModel::mZoomLevels(zooms, zooms + 10);
```

Answer (score 5):

Arrays do not have `begin` and `end` members. You can use array name for `begin` and array name plus length for the end:

```
const std::vector mZoomLevels(zooms, zooms+10);
```

In C++11, you can use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), like this:

```
const std::vector mZoomLevels(std::begin(zooms), std::end(zooms));
```

In both cases, it is a good idea to declare your `zooms` array file-static or hide it in a namespace, to make sure that its name does not "pollute" the global namespace.

Comment: If you have C++11 and you want to initialize the vector, there is no need to create the array, just use *list-initialization*: `const std::vector<int> ImageModel::mZoomLevels{1,2,3,4...};` --less code and you remove an unneeded array. That is if you *really* want to use a `std::vector<int>`... which I am not too sure...

Answer (score 1):

zooms is an C-style array that has no members and methods, i.e. `zooms.begin` and `zooms.end` make no sense. If you use a C++11 compatible compiler, try `std::begin(zooms)` and `std::end(zooms)`

Answer (score 1):

Normal C++ arrays can't have members.  However, you're looking for static dispatch, and that works fine with overload resolution by parameter type.  So C++11 provides `std::begin` and `std::end` non-member functions.  (This has already been mentioned.)

Get used to the best practice for calling non-member functions as follows (it really helps as you write generic template code):

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;

const std::vector mZoomLevels(begin(zooms), end(zooms));
```

This will work correctly no matter what type the container `zooms` is, and it will take advantage of ADL (argument-dependent lookup, sometimes called Koenig lookup) to find implementations of `begin` and `end` in the same namespace if `zooms` had some custom class type.

BTW, `std::begin` and `std::end` are provided by C++11, but you can write your own easily enough for earlier versions:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T* begin( T (&a)[N] ) { return a; }

template <typename T, size_t N>
T* end( T (&a)[N] ) { return a + N; }
```

Comment: Why `using`? There's no need for ADL here.

Comment: @DeadMG: Why not `using`?  If he gets into the habit of doing it right, he won't suddenly have problems when using it inside a template.

Comment: A template wouldn't change anything. He's calling it on a native array- `std::begin` and `std::end` will always be chosen.

Comment: @DeadMG: Think of the case where `zooms` is a parameter, not a global variable, and the parameter type is templatized to allow any container type.  The code in the question is a SSCE, not necessarily as complex as the real situation likely to be encountered.

Comment: @DeadMG: Why `using` when there is no need for ADL? The *using* directive brings a symbol into scope, that is almost orthogonal to ADL... granted that you need it if you want ADL support, but that is not the *only* purpose of the using declaration.

Comment: Why do all answers provide a C++11 solution with `std::begin` and `std::end` when you wan use *list-initialization* on the vector directly (and remove the need for the array in the first place)?

Comment: Yeah, all the other effects are entirely negative instead of only mostly negative. @BenVoigt: Maybe, but there's no indication the OP needs that support.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: My solution doesn't require C++11.  And I was going for "best way to initialize a vector from some other container" as opposed to "best way to initialize a vector from a literal list".

Comment: I think that the suggestion with the template functions begin and end is very good. Thnk you !

Answer (score 1):

I would follow different approaches here depending on whether you have access to C++11 or not.

In C++03, I would use a plain array (since it is const), and probably not even in the class, but in a private namespace in the implementation file (since it is private, assuming that only one translation unit has the definitions for members of `ImageModel`).

```
// cpp
namespace {
   static int gZoomLevels[] = { 1, 2, ... };
}
```

If you really want to keep using the `std::vector<int>` approach I would create a helper function in the translation unit that defines the member and use that to create the `std::vector`, without creating a different variable with static duration:

```
namespace {
   static std::vector<int> chooseANameForInitializer() {
       int data[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
       return std::vector<int>( data, data + (sizeof data/sizeof *data) );
   }
}
const std::vector<int> ImageModel::mZoomLevels = chooseANameForInitializer();
```

In C++11 I would use `std::array<int,...>` instead, as that avoids the dynamic allocation and the cost of the extra indirection. Granted it is not a great gain, but there is no point in having a `std::vector<int>` when you don't need any of the features it offers.

```
class ImageModel
{
private:
    static const std::array<int,10> mZoomLevels;  
};
// cpp:
const std::array<int,10> ImageModel::mZoomLevels = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Again, if you insist on having a `std::vector<int>` then you can use *list-initialization*

```
const std::vector<int> ImageModel::mZoomLevels{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```